# Datastore Query filters accumulating on subsequent calls

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am making a RESTFul API. I have the following endpoint

```
/users/getByState/stateId
```

I have several users in the database. 3 users are from say, Texas, 1 from New York.

When I call the endpoint the first time, either by

```
/user/getByState/tx
```

or by

```
/user/getByState/ny
```

I get a result, but calling immediately the endpoint using the other state id, returns an empty array and the message {"moreResults": "NO_MORE_RESULTS"}

Sending the query to the console log shows me that the first time the query only has one filter.. lets say

```
FILTER:{stateID:'tx'}
```

But the second time, instead of changing the filter option to 'ny' it instead adds another filter so now in the console log I see

```
FILTER:{stateId:'tx'}
FILTER:{stateId:'ny'}
```

Which will obviously always return an empty array because it will never find stateId='tx' AND stateId='ny'

I don't understand why the cloud datastore client is adding a filter to a CONST!!

If I call the endpoint 7 times, I see 7 filters. Only after I redeploy the filters "clear"

How do I clear the filters before running the query again? Have searched about this in the cloud datastore documentation but there is no information about filters concatenating after each call

Am I missing something? This is my code:

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const datastore=Datastore();
const query=datastore.createQuery("user");

exports.get_user_by_state =(req,res,next) => {
   const pageCursor = req.query.cursor;
   const userState=req.params.stateId;

   const selectQuery = query
    .filter('stateId',userState)

   console.log(selectQuery);

   selectQuery.run({cache:false})
    .then((results) => {
      res.json(results);
      })
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

> You need a new query object for each and every query. So, the query object should be created inside the block.

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const datastore = Datastore();

exports.get_user_by_state =(req,res,next) => {
   const pageCursor = req.query.cursor;
   const query      = datastore.createQuery("user");
   const userState  = req.params.stateId;

   const selectQuery = query
    .filter('stateId',userState)

   console.log(selectQuery);

   selectQuery.run({cache:false})
    .then((results) => {
      res.json(results);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err));
   }
```